# get the average that need to match the condition of other columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements, mean

Here's the data:

```
data <-tibble::tribble(
          ~PROPNUM, ~initial_date,  ~third_date,  ~OIL,  ~GAS,   ~Prod_date,
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  775L,    0L,  "9/30/2011",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30", 2210L,  477L, "10/31/2011",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30", 1455L, 1008L, "11/30/2011",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30", 1054L,  875L, "12/31/2011",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  992L, 3003L,  "1/31/2012",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  828L,  745L,  "2/29/2012",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  485L,  533L,  "3/31/2012",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30", 1084L,  821L,  "4/30/2012",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  677L,  623L,  "5/31/2012",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  658L,  598L,  "6/30/2012",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  643L,  624L,  "7/31/2012",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  608L,  619L,  "8/31/2012",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  559L,  561L,  "9/30/2012",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  558L,  567L, "10/31/2012",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  514L,  491L, "11/30/2012",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  531L,  462L, "12/31/2012",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  481L,  480L,  "1/31/2013",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  436L,  424L,  "2/28/2013",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  449L,  488L,  "3/31/2013",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  429L,  495L,  "4/30/2013",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  422L,  511L,  "5/31/2013",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  395L,  497L,  "6/30/2013",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  382L,  519L,  "7/31/2013",
    "49-005-61202",  "2011-09-30", "2011-11-30",  391L,  519L,  "8/31/2013"
    )
```

Thank you so much for the reply!

I tested on my own data using AKrun and PaulS's method, but it's returning 0 obs . 2 variables, the warning I got is "All formats failed to parse. No formats found. "
I uploaded the data again, this one should reproduce my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `base R`

```
data$Prod_date <- as.Date(data$Prod_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
data$initial_date <- as.Date(data$initial_date)
data$third_date <- as.Date(data$third_date)
subdat <- subset(data, Prod_date <= third_date & Prod_date >= initial_date)
aggregate(OIL ~ PROPNUM, subdat, mean)
```

-output

```
   PROPNUM  OIL
1 49-005-61202 1480
```

Comment: I tested on my own data using this method, but it's returning 0 obs . 2 variables, the warning I got is "All formats failed to parse. No formats found." The data is reloaded for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Solicia I used your example to create this.  Maybe your example got changed only for me

Comment: Do you get the result? Now this partial data only have 1 propnum, I tested the code with the sample data and it's not working.

Comment: @Solicia I guess I showed the output I received as well.  It is working fine for me with your sample data

Comment: @Solicia Probably, you have changed the data again?

Comment: I just did it, and subdat is 0 obs . of 6 variables

Comment: @Solicia try the update.  This is based on your new data

Comment: It works!! Thnk you!! Why am I getting "All formats failed to parse. No formats found. " this warning?

Comment: @Solicia Your earlier data had columns in `%m/%d/%Y` format for all those date columns, whereas in the new one, it is not the case.  Some of them are `%Y-%m-%d` which is the default format for `Date` class, thus I don't have to specify the format in `as.Date`, for the other column it is `%m/%d/%Y`, so it needs that format argument for conversion.  Make sure you check the date format of the date columns before conversion

Comment: @Solicia There is an automatic way to convert the columns to Date class without speifying i.e. `library(parsedate);as.Date(parse_date(yourdata$yourcol))` will detec the format automatically

Answer (score 2):

Here is one that is similar to @PaulS one, but using `between` from `dyplr` and it is also much longer:-)

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("date"), mdy)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(helper = ifelse(between(Prod_date, initial_date, third_date), 1, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(PROPNUM, helper) %>% 
  summarise(Avg_OIL = mean(OIL)) %>% 
  filter(helper == 1) %>% 
  select(-helper)

  PROPNUM      Avg_OIL
  <fct>          <dbl>
1 49-005-27619   1613.
2 49-005-61086   2154.
3 49-005-61202   1480 
4 49-005-61268   7063
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, which is based on `lubridate::mdy`, to filter out all cases outside the dates interval, and `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>% 
  group_by(PROPNUM) %>% 
  filter(mdy(Prod_date) <= mdy(third_date) & mdy(Prod_date) >= mdy(initial_date)) %>% 
  summarise(avgOil = mean(OIL))

#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   PROPNUM      avgOil
#>   <fct>         <dbl>
#> 1 49-005-27619  1613.
#> 2 49-005-61086  2154.
#> 3 49-005-61202  1480 
#> 4 49-005-61268  7063.
```

Comment: Thank you PaulS! I see that for this sample data, the format for all dates (initial, third, prod) are factors and it's working. But my real data the formats are date and it returns "0 obs. 2 variables"

Comment: Well, then, you should share your real data, @Solicia!

Comment: Hello I updated the data and what my issue is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%between%` from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

# convert do date
data_cols <- grep("date$", names(data), value = TRUE)
setDT(data)[, (data_cols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, "%m/%d/%y"), .SDcols = data_cols]

# calculate
data[Prod_date %between% list(initial_date, third_date)][,.(avg_oil = mean(OIL)), by = PROPNUM]
```